# Index on objectid field - $in operator - strange keysExamined

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a MongoDB 3.4 replicaset with a collection "page" where all documents have a "site" field (which is an ObjectId). "site" field has only 100 possible values. I have created an index on this field via `db.page.createIndex({site:1})`. There are about 3.6 millions documents in the "page" collection.

Now, I see logs like this in the mongod.log file

> command db.page command: count { count: "page", query: { site: { $in:
> [ ObjectId('A'), ObjectId('B'), ObjectId('C'), ObjectId('D'),
> ObjectId('E'), ObjectId('F'), ObjectId('G'), ObjectId('H'),
> ObjectId('I'), ObjectId('J'),, ObjectId('K'),, ObjectId('L') ] } } }
> planSummary: IXSCAN { site: 1 } keysExamined:221888
> docsExamined:221881 numYields:1786 reslen:44...

I don't understand the "keysExamined:221888" -> there are only 100 possible values, so my understanding would be that I would see keysExamined:100 at most, and here I would actually expect to see "keysExamined:12". What am I missing? For info, here is an explain on the request:

```
PRIMARY> db.page.explain().count({ site: { $in: [ ObjectId('A'), ObjectId('F'), ObjectId('H'), ObjectId('G'), ObjectId('I'), ObjectId('B'), ObjectId('C'), ObjectId('J'), ObjectId('K'), ObjectId('D'), ObjectId('E'), ObjectId('L') ] } } )
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "db.page",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "site" : {
                                "$in" : [
                                        ObjectId("B"),
                                        ObjectId("C"),
                                        ObjectId("D"),
                                        ObjectId("E"),
                                        ObjectId("F"),
                                        ObjectId("A"),
                                        ObjectId("G"),
                                        ObjectId("H"),
                                        ObjectId("I"),
                                        ObjectId("J"),
                                        ObjectId("K"),
                                        ObjectId("L")
                                ]
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COUNT",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "site" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "site_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "site" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "site" : [
                                                        "[ObjectId('B'), ObjectId('B')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('C'), ObjectId('C')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('D'), ObjectId('D')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('E'), ObjectId('E')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('F'), ObjectId('F')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('A'), ObjectId('A')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('G'), ObjectId('G')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('H'), ObjectId('H')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('I'), ObjectId('I')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('J'), ObjectId('J')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('K'), ObjectId('K')]",
                                                        "[ObjectId('L'), ObjectId('L')]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "9a18351b5211",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.4.18",
                "gitVersion" : "4410706bef6463369ea2f42399e9843903b31923"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
PRIMARY>
```

I know we are on a fairly old MongoDB version and we are planning to upgrade soon to 5.0.X (via incremental upgrade to  3.6 / 4.0 / 4.2 / 4.4). Is there a fix in the next versions to your knowledge?

Comment: I don't know MongoDB intimately, but I think you are confusing unique key values, with the key entries in the index. Each document will have an index entry.

Comment: Hum, not sure why but I started the question with "hello everyone" and it is not displayed :'(

Comment: You shouldn't add fluff like greetings or thanks in a question. If you add it, it will be edited out by your peers. In this case it was likely that myedit - which coincided with your edit - overwrote yours.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you for you feedback, I was expecting something like "keysExamined:12, docsExamined:221881" so unique "subkeys" inside the index bu I will check more deeply the working on the index as per your suggestion

Comment: So after checking I realized I was expecting mongodb to use counted b-trees for its index but that is not the case, hence mongo has indeed to go through all the subkeys of the index. Details in https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/server-7745

Answer (score 0):

So after checking I realized I was expecting mongodb to use counted b-trees for its index but that is not the case, hence mongo has indeed to go through all the subkeys of the index. Details in jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/server-7745

Hence at the moment count request will run in O(N) for N docs if indexes are used

Comment: Please update your original question so that everyone knows